# Partially appplied function with (.) seems to take too few arguments

Tags: haskell

So, we have three functions:

```
A :: [([String], [String])] -> [String] -> [String]
A = B . C "*" f

B :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
C :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

The thing that confuses me about this is that A takes two arguments, and those arguments will then be the arguments to C when A is called. Then the result of C will be the argument(s) to B, but how is that possible since B is supposed to take two arguments, when C like every other function I've seen so far in Haskell will just return one value.

From what I can gather from the dot operator:

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Using the dot in A allows it to be this "point free" style, and makes it more readable. But what it says is:

```
A x y = B (C "*" f x y)
```

But I'm obviously missing something, since if I write it like that then:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Maybe a0'
              with actual type `Maybe [[Char]]'
```

And then I'm stumped.

Comment: Every function in Haskell takes *exactly* one parameter. `a -> b -> c` is short for `a -> (b -> c)`. So it is a function that *returns* another function.

Comment: Ye, so I thought I had that down, and how partially applied functions then can work. But I can't see how that makes A work differently in the first snippet and the third one if that is how the (.) function works. Since it feels like that call to A with two arguments should then wait for another one, since those two will just lead to one argument from C's result into B.

Comment: wel `A` is implemented as `A x y = B (C "*" f x) y`, so `y` is *not* part of the `C "*" ...` subexpression.

Comment: `(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)` is a complicated way of writing `(f . g) x = f (g x)`. now if you just substitute this, purely mechanistically, into `A x = (B . C "*" f) x` you get `A x = B ((C "*" f) x) = B (C "*" f x)` and so `A x y = B (C "*" f x) y`. that's all. we can always add as much arguments as needed into the `L = R` equations, (`L x = R x`, `L x y = R x y`, ...). This is called "eta-expansion" (or "eta-conversion" which goes both ways -- adding, or removing arguments as well). (meta: *accepting* an answer signals you've *no more questions* about it...)

Comment: Okay, so I see how that works now, but what then where you say `A x y = B (C "*" f x) y`, C is still missing an argument in my mind. I can see in the approved answer that it is correct, and since it works. But I still feel like I dont know _why_. Like I wouldn't be able to see a case myself where I would write this. And maybe it's just all about practice, I was just wondering if there was anything I'm missing. (I'll keep the meta _rules_ in mind, thanks ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the dot in A allows it to be this "point free" style, and makes it more readable. But what it says is:
>
> ```
> A x y = B (C "*" f x y)
> ```

What it says is:

```
 A x = B (C "*" f x)
```

since `B` has type `B :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a`, it will return a function, and thus we can add an extra parameter:

```
A x y = B (C "*" f x) y
```

but these are *different*. Note that the `(.)` makes a chain for one parameter.

After all `(.)` is implemented like you say as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

So here `B` is the left function, and `(C "*" f)` is the right function. So that means that `(.) B (C "*" f)` is equivalent to:

```
(.) B (C "*" f) x = B (C "*" f x)
```

If we analyze the types, we see:

```
(.)    :: (b             ->    c   ) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
B      :: (d -> Maybe d) -> (d -> d)
--------------------------------------------------------------
b ~ (d -> Maybe d), c ~ (d -> d)
```

so that means the type of `(.) B` is `(a -> (d -> Maybe d)) -> (a -> (d -> d))`, or less verbose `(a -> d -> Maybe d) -> a -> d -> d`.

Now we can analyze the type of `C "*" f`:

```
C   :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
"*" ::       String
f   ::              ([a] -> [a])
--------------------------------------------------------------------
a ~ String
```

We do not know what `f` is here, but we will assume that it is a `[String] -> [String]` function, so the matching works.

This thus means that `C "*" f` has type `[([String], [String])] -> [String] -> Maybe [String]`.

Now the types match, since:

```
(.) B   ::  (          a ->                d ->    Maybe d       ) -> a -> d -> d
C "*" f ::   [([String], [String])] -> [String] -> Maybe [String]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a ~ [([String], [String])], d ~ [String]
```

So this means that `(.) B (C "*" f)` has type `[([String], [String])] -> String -> String`. This indeed holds if we determine this with ghci:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| b :: (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> a
Prelude| b = undefined
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :{
Prelude| c :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [([a], [a])] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
Prelude| c = undefined
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t b . c "*" undefined
b . c "*" undefined
  :: [([[Char]], [[Char]])] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
```

Comment: Amazing, that cleared it up, thank you! I should probably practice a bit on this type analysis on functions. I kind of figured that the types was enough to answer my question, and not all of the functions. So to pat myself on the back, maybe that's something ^^